# I dont see any problem in this code but postman gives me an error?

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose

```js
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const Schema=mongoose.Schema;

const ProductSchema=new Schema({
    name:{type:String,required:true},
    price:{type:Number,required:true}
});

const Product=mongoose.model('product',ProductSchema);

module.exports=Product;
```

```js
router.put('/:productid',(req,res,next)=>{
    product.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.params.productid},req.body)
    .then((data)=>{
        res.status(200).json({
            message:'Product updated',
            'Data':data
        })
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error),
        res.status(500).json({
            Message:error
        })
    })
   
});
```

Iam learning REST API so im trying to build one, i cant do the put request from postman. It gives me an error. Below i will attach screenshots of my code and the postman error.

**My code**

[image]

**post man sent data and the reply error**

[image: post man sent data and the reply error]

Comment: please post codes, not images

Comment: Please add the code from the images to your question, it's easy. Clicking a link to another page only discourages people to help you.

Comment: make sure you did `const product = require('../models/product')`

Comment: @HilarionGalushka I did :/

Comment: show your node.js console output when the error is thrown

Comment: show your product model

Comment: @HilarionGalushka Please checkout my product model

Comment: Show us where you are importing (requiring) Product on your route file. I think you have a capitalization problem.

Comment: @HilarionGalushka It was the capitalization problem when im requiring the Product.. Now it works. Thanks a lot bro.

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting model this way:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('product',ProductSchema);
```

Then import this way:

```
const product = require('path/to/model/product');
```